# Is it possible connect from website to selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Is it possible connect from website to selenium? I mean website itself is connecting to selenium for instance using JS.

Comment: can you please elaborate. what are you trying to achieve. what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Just imagine that you have run webbrowser on remote machine...but you don't have access directly to this machine I mean you are not able run webbrowser on this machine for instance using webdriver selenium etc. It this reason my question. I need find out some way to run tests content in webbrowser this machine without access directly to this machine.

Comment: There is some support in TestNG framework too. to run tests on remote machine. did u have look at that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link for implementing Selenium Grid.

http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html

Using Selenium Grid, you don't need to remotely access the machines. But if you are trying to launch tests on already Open browser instances(locally/remotely) - then thats not possible with Selenium.

Comment: thank you for your answer. " But if you are trying to launch tests on already Open browser instances(locally/remotely) - then that's not possible with Selenium." exactly that I had in mind. As I thought it is not possible in selenium but I'd like make sure

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much requested since a loooong time. But doesn't seem practical as of now. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary